# SUMIFS Function in SQL - SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY ) is not working

Tags: sql, partitioning, partition, sumifs, partition-by

I used the SUMIFS formula in my google sheet to sum the product cost based on Order Id and Composite Parent SKU if it is equal to SKU. However, I cannot get the result I want using SUM OVER PARTITION BY in SQL.

Here is my data:

| Order_Id | SKU | Composite_Parent_SKU | Quantity | Unit_Cost | Product_Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | SKU001 |  | 1 | 20 | 5 |
| 00001 | SKU001X2 |  | 1 | 30 |  |
| 00001 | SKU001 | SKU001X2 | 2 |  | 10 |

What I get if using SUM OVER PARTITION BY:

```
CASE WHEN Unit_Cost = 0 THEN 0
WHEN Unit_Cost > 0 AND Product_Cost > 0 THEN SUM(Product_Cost * Quantity)
ELSE SUM(Product_Cost * Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY Order_Id, SKU) END
```

| Order_Id | SKU | Composite_Parent_SKU | Quantity | Unit_Cost | Product_Cost | My_Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | SKU001 |  | 1 | 20 | 5 | 15 |
| 00001 | SKU001X2 |  | 1 | 30 |  |  |
| 00001 | SKU001 | SKU001X2 | 2 |  | 10 | 0 |

Here is the result that I want:

| Order_Id | SKU | Composite_Parent_SKU | Quantity | Unit_Cost | Product_Cost | My_Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | SKU001 |  | 1 | 20 | 5 | 5 |
| 00001 | SKU001X2 |  | 1 | 30 |  | 10 |
| 00001 | SKU001 | SKU001X2 | 2 |  | 10 |  |

Could anyone please help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this looks more like a recursive cte solution is need of the cpmüosue parent sku go deeper than one level

Comment: @nbk  Do you mean use WITH UNION ALL?

Comment: yes you could call it that but we prefer the name recursive cte, so that we all know what is meant